# What's the proper way to add a field at a given place in a form?

Tags: 8, forms

I'd like to add a checkbox right before the `</th>` tag of each column of a table.

According to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/7658/85453), we should preferably use `#prefix` and `#suffix` over `#weight`.

So, here is my `hook_form_alter()`:

```php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_admin_permissions') {
    $form['select_all'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Select all the column'),
      '#prefix' => '<th>',
      '#suffix' => '</th>',
    );
  }
}
```

But my checkbox is at the bottom of the page.

Since I didn't understand why we use an additional `latitude` array in the linked example, I also tried with an additional array:

```php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_admin_permissions') {
    $form['table_header']['select_all'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Select all the column'),
      '#prefix' => '<th>',
      '#suffix' => '</th>',
    );
    $form['table_header']['select_all'] = $form['select_all'];
    unset($form['select_all']);
  }
}
```

In that case my checkbox does not appear at all.

It seems another strategy could be using `array_search` and `array_merge` like suggested [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2008-03-17/insert-new-field-into-array-using#comment-1271222), but I couldn't make it work.

To provide more info about the form I want to override, I put a break-point at the second line of `my_module_form_alter()`:

[image: Xdebug vars]

In my case, this is what I'd like to do:

[image: What I'd like to do]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add select all element to the table headers? You can do that by creating a `tableselect` element. You'll have to check the type of the element being overridden, whether it's a `table` or `tableselect`, and alter it accordingly. It's not really something that can be answered here though, as it's dependent upon the element being altered, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan, yes I'm trying to add a select all element to the table headers in _/admin/people/permissions_, to be able to select a full column in one click. How can I know if the type of the element to be overridden is `table` or `tableselect`?

Comment: You'll have to debug the #type on the element you are altering.

Comment: @Jaypan, I edited my question to add the result. It seems to be `table`.

Comment: You'll need to manipulate the array to be a tableselect element, in the proper format. You'll have to play with tableselects to understand how they should be formatted, then change the #type to tableselect, and alter any elements of the array accordingly.

Comment: Just to make sure @Jaypan, since I'd like to add a "select all" checkbox in `<th>` (to select all the permissions of a given column in _/admin/people/permissions_) are you sure `tableselect` is the way to go? I found your [tutorial for D7](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/themeing-drupal-7-forms-tables-checkboxes-or-radios) about it and it seems to add a checkbox in rows but not in columns.